# Selecting element based on attribute order in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am working on a project using the Html-Agility-Pack and I need to build a list of each link that has an `href` attribute as its *first* attribute. What XPath expression would be used for this?

Example (I would want to only select the first):

1. `<a href="http://someurl.com"/>`
2. `<a id="someid" href="http://someurl.com"/>`

Comment: Is not a good idea but in theory this can be done as HtmlAgilityPack parses the attributes in the same order they appear on the Html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, don't do that.**

You really don't want to select elements based upon the ordering of their attributes ***because attribute order is arbitrary in HTML and XML***.  Find another criteria to limit your selections:

- attribute presence or attribute value
- child element presence or string value
- preceding element value, possibly a label
- etc

You want to choose a criteria that's invariant across all instances of the HTML/XML documents you may encounter.   Attribute order is not such a criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here. Will do!